# A closed subset of a manifold is precompact (Lemma 1.10 from Lee)

Tags: manifolds

I can't understand the end of the proof of the following lemma from "Introduction to smooth manifolds" by Lee

> Lemma 1.10: Every topological manifold has a countable basis of precompact
>   coordinate balls

In order to prove it he takes a manifold $M$ which is covered by a countable subcover $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}$.

A the end of the proof he concludes that, given a precompact ball $V \subset U_i $, $\bar{V}$ is compact in $U_i$ and $\bar{V}$ is closed in $M$. And this is clear for me.

I don't understand the sentence that concludes the proof: " (given that $\bar{V}$ is closed in $M$) It follows that the closure of $V$ in $M$ is the same as its closure in $U_i$, so $V$ is precompact in $M$ as well."

What does it mean "is the same as"? How can I conclude that $V$ is precompact?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Necessity of closedness in going from precompactness in chart to precompactness in the manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260353/necessity-of-closedness-in-going-from-precompactness-in-chart-to-precompactness)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the following:

Give $U_i$ the subspace topology. Then as $V \subseteq U_i$, we can take the closure of $V$ inside $U_i$ with the subspace topology: $cl_{U_i}(V)$. But also $V \subseteq M$, so we can take the closure of $V$ in $M$, which is $cl_M(V)$. The author claims that

$$cl_{U_i}(V) = cl_{M}(V)$$

Comment: but why can he claim that?

Comment: $\overline{V}$ is compact in $U_i$ thus also compact in $M$. A compact set is closed in a Hausdorff space. Does that answer your question?